# I want make some thing like that in my web.php. But I dont know what should I write

Tags: laravel

Hi can you please solve my problem? My problem is i want to access my    controller in a master page

in my **web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [LayoutController::class, 'home']{

    $abouts = DB::table('home_abouts')->first();
    
    return view('home', compact('abouts'));

});
```

in my **master.blade.php**
```

```
<div class="section-title">
  <h2>About Us</strong></h2>
</div>

<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-right">
    <h2> {{ $abouts->title }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ $abouts->short_dis }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 pt-4 pt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left">
    <p>
    {{ $abouts->long_dis }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
How can I write this correctly on web.php? I don't know what should I write now
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using two various methods:

- Using a closure
- Using a controller method

If you want to use a closure, rewrite it like this:

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    $abouts = DB::table('home_abouts')->first();
    return view('home', compact('abouts'));
});
```

And if you want to use controllers (recommended), do this:

```php
Route::get('/', [LayoutController::class, 'home']);
```

Then implement your `home()` method in `LayoutController`.

Comment: Route::get('/', function() {
    $abouts = DB::table('home_abouts')->first();
    return view('home', compact('abouts'));
});.    If I write like U are mentioned it where I will write LayoutController::class

Answer (score 0):

just to add to [@WebPajooh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72516610/6330083) there are [view routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#view-routes)

```php
Route::view('/', 'home', ['abouts' => DB::table('home_abouts')->first()]);
```

but using closure-based routes becomes a mess really fast, so better stick with controller variant

Answer (score 0):

```
// inside your web.php file 
// make sure MasterController is imported
Route::get('/', [MasterController::class, 'index']);

// in your controller
public function index(){

    $abouts = DB::table('home_abouts')->first();
    return view('master', [
           'abouts' => $abouts
    ]);// thats master.blade.php 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use controllers

Inside your web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LayoutController;

Route::get('/', [LayoutController::class, 'home']);
```

And inside your controller LayoutController, create a home function

```
public function home() 
{
    $abouts = DB::table('home_abouts')->first();
    
    return view('home', ['abouts' => $abouts]);
}
```

Then create a blade inside resources/views, for instance, let's say home.blade.php

{{ $abouts->table_column_here }}